# Obtaining useful information from graph obtained via Monte-Carlo Simulations

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, matlab, monte-carlo

I've been running Monte Carlo Simulations on some Matlab code and then plot the graph shown below. I was just wondering what useful information I could collect from this graph?

[image]

Edit:
[image]

fit 1-Lognormal
fit 3-Gamma

Comment: For one thing, either the title on the figure is wrong or the the axis labels are swapped. Usually the dependent variable is plotted on the x-axis.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for the comment. The Unique Threshold Strains are not dependant on their frequency of occurrence I believe and it is the other way around.

Comment: I do not think that only from this graph you can claim more than the distribution is like a log-normal. What kind of information you wanted to achieve? How did you simulate the MC run?

Comment: @7raiden7 With regards to simulating the MC run, I was essentially sampling randomly from the Normal Distributions associated with the parameters that make up the equation which is used to calculate the "Threshold Strain". The graph above was obtained after 10,000 such iterations. I was hoping to get an idea of the probabilities of occurrence associated with the unique Threshold Strains. Cheers.

Comment: It seems to be a log-normal distribution. Could you please post an extract of your code?

Comment: @7raiden7 I've added the code in the original question. I've just added the code that runs the Monte Carlo Simulation and have given an explanation above the code of what I am trying to do. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A Monte Carlo simulation easily gives you access to the mean and variance of the variable you've been simulating, and to the probability of this variable being higher/smaller than a given value. You can also try to guess if the distribution you see can possibly correspond to a standard law, and use some tests to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering what you mean by a "standard law"? Cheers

Comment: Sorry, I mean "common probability distributions". Like Normal, lognormal, gamma, chi-squared...

Comment: Thanks. One of the earlier commenter's suggested the graph resembled a Log-Normal Distribution. Given that, I will just take the log of the data and then run Normality tests. I was just wondering do you think a goodness of fit test would do the trick as a Normality test? Cheers.

Comment: I guess so, you can even try a chi-squared test, which is the easiest/most straightforward way to check it.

Comment: @7raiden7 I ran a test in Matlab and apparently the data used to plot this graph isn't part of a Chi-Squared Distribution. I was therefore wondering what you think I could do from here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem in communication, I meant the chi-squared test, to verify whether your distribution is log-normal or not. 

You can simply use Matlab "dfittool(X)", where $X$ is your random variable, and try to see what happens.

Comment: @7raiden7 Thank you very much for your patience. I have attached the fitted plot to the original question and was wondering if I could get some feedback off you? Thanks again.

Comment: @7raiden7 Neither Lognormal nor Gamma appear to be a good fit for the plot. I think this may be due to the fact that it is in fact (through an increased number of iterations) tending towards a bimodal Normal Distribution.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately those fits are not suitable. How do you know the limit distribution is a bimodal normal distribution? As soon as you know the theoretical distribution do the following: denote $f_i=f(x_i)$ the theoretical frequencies, $F_i$ the observed frequencies (after having divided in classes), and calculate: $\chi^2=\frac{\sum (f_i-F_i)^2}{N}$. then we can analyse the result.